# Getting started on functions need help inputting numbers (beginner)

Tags: c, function

I was wondering how I can input the numbers using a function with the code written below, and a bit stuck on how I can input and give it an output I am just starting out on functions level 0 at it basically.

```
int addTwoInt(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &addTwoInt(<#int a#>, <#int b#>));
    // printf("The two numbers added are %d", addTwoInt);
}

int addTwoInt(int a, int b)
{
    int sum;
    sum = a + b;
    return sum;
    printf("The sum of the numbers are %d", sum);
}
```

Comment: You first read the input into a variable. Then pass the variable to the function. These are two operations. And yes, having anything after the `return` statement in a function does not make sense as won't ever be executed.

Comment: `int a = 0,b=0; scanf("%d",&a); scanf("%d",&b); int result = addTwoInt(a,b);`

Comment: thanks, I just looked back at it and rethought about it, I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
int addTwoInt(int a, int b);
int main(void)
{
int x;
int y;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
scanf("%d", &y);

int z = addTwoInt(x, y);
printf("%d", z);

//printf("The two numbers added are %d", addTwoInt);
}

int addTwoInt(int a, int b)
{
int sum;
sum = a + b;
printf("The sum of the numbers are %d", sum);
return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for cleaner way to add two numbers or other arithmetic operations u can simply do it in return statement just like this:

```
int addTwoInts(int a, int b){
return a+b
}
```